# subsonic . navigate among records ,view,query

Tags: subsonic, navigation, record

i'm some newbie in this matter of .net
i'm trying understand this new paradigm
i began with linq for SQl

but i found this library, kind of framework of T4
more specifically: subsonic T4

i think it could be very usefull

but the support docs outside are very scarce

my first intention is use them in the very simple form: a catalog
lets say... Users

so...
how can i use the model generated with subsonic
( using the iactiverecord)

to implement the record-navigational part.,...???!!!

i mean
i want a simple form
to create, delete or modify records
and that is fairy easy

but
what about to move among records ?

i found how to get the first, the last record..

but how can i advance or go back among them???

how can i order the records..?

it seems everytime imust query the table..
its so?

but how can imove among the records i already got?

all of the exmples found are very simple
dont touch the matter and/ or are repetitive everywhere

so.. please

if anybody can help me
or give more references...

i'd thank you a lot

gmo camilo

Answer (score 0):

SubSonic can return a List of your objects if you call ExecuteTypedList or ToList on a query e.g.

```
 List<Product> products = Products.All().ToList();
```

Once you've got a List then you can move around it in memory. Have a look at the following references to learn more about collections in .net:

1. [System.Collections.Generic Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx)
2. [IEnumerable<(Of <(T>)>) Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx)
3. [List<(Of <(T>)>) Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)